# Error while using Node html parser : error TS2339: does not exist on type '(TextNode & { valid: boolean; }) | (HTMLElement & { valid: boolean; })

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm **scraping** the website for my project and for that I'm using axios and for the html parser using  node-html-parser using this i'm getting this error while parsing the dom

```
  " Error TS2339: Property
    'querySelectorAll' does not exist on type '(TextNode & { valid: boolean; }) | (HTMLElement & { valid: boolean; })' "
```

and the code i wrote is :

```
axios.get('url',  config).then((res) => {
      var rawHtml = res.data; 
      const root = parse(rawHtml);
      // console.log(root.querySelectorAll('option')); //Error here
     root: HTMLElement   = root.removeWhitespace() ;  //Error
      const data    =  root.querySelectorAll('option') ;
```

in short wherever I'm using any method of node html parse I'm getting this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the problem the other day. This worked for me: try casting your created element as an HTMLElement.

```
const root = parse(rawHtml) as HTMLElement;
```

Now it should have query selector functions available to it without type errors.

Comment: I'm pouring over the documentation and nowhere does it talk about casting. For my future self, how did you figure that out? I spent way too long logging `parse` with no luck in getting what I needed.

Comment: @MixMasterMike I forget, I think I just tried a bunch of casts until the error stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love them union of intersection types. I hit this tonight and did the following...

```js
import { HTMLElement, parse, TextNode } from 'node-html-parser';

type ParseResult = (TextNode & { valid: boolean; }) | (HTMLElement & { valid: boolean; });

const result: ParseResult = parse(rawHTML);
if (result.valid) {
    const root = (result as unknown) as HTMLElement;
    const element = root.querySelector("...");
    // Do something interesting with element here...
}
```

It was necessary to cast `result as unknown` first because trying to directly cast `result as HTMLElement` is an error when all strict checks are enabled in tsconfig.json.